# TypeError : callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

**i get a callback is not a function only when i try to add a new
 parameter  erreur= TypeError: callback is not a function
     at services.js:72 i tried to add reference to the function when i romoved evrything works fine here's my code at service.js  I hope you'll help me.**

```
    .factory('Payement', function ($http, $ionicLoading) {
            return {
                saveContratEtudant: function (_nb_piece1,_nb_piece2,_shortadresse,_govClt,_villeClt,_localiteClt,_voieClt,_cod_logem,_adresse_logem,_govLogem,_gelgLogem, _dateDel,_dateEffet,_dateExp,_nomAssure, _prenomAssure ,_piece2,_numDocument,_typeContrat,_natureContrat,_piece1,_dateNais,_email,_phone,_IdTrans,_reference,_numDocuemnt,_codePostal,_adresse,_typedocu,_sexeClt,_tarif,_frais ,_tva, _tcc, callback) {

                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url:SAVE_ETUDIANT,
                        timeout: 10000,
                        data: {
                            nb_piece1:_nb_piece1,
                            nb_piece2:_nb_piece2,
                            shortadresse:_shortadresse,
                            govClt:_govClt,
                            villeClt:_villeClt,
                            localiteClt:_localiteClt,
                            voieClt:_voieClt,
                            cod_logem:_cod_logem,
                            adresse_logem:_adresse_logem,
                            govLogem:_govLogem,
                            gelgLogem:_gelgLogem,
                            dateDelivra:_dateDel,
                            dateEffet:_dateEffet,
                            dateExp:_dateExp,
                            nomAssure:_nomAssure,
                            prenomAssure:_prenomAssure,
                            piece2:_piece2,
                            numDocument:_numDocument,
                            typeContrat:_typeContrat,
                            natureContrat:_natureContrat,
                            piece1:_piece1,
                            dateNais:_dateNais,
                            email:_email,
                            phone:_phone,
                            IdTrans: _IdTrans,
                            reference:_reference
                            numDocuemnt:_numDocuemnt,
                            codePostal:_codePostal,
                            adresse:_adresse,
                            typedocu:_typedocu,
                            sexeClt:_sexeClt,
                            //nbr_piece: ,
                            tarif : _tarif ,
                            frais : _frais,
                            tva :_tva,
                            tcc :_tcc,
                            //reference :_reference


                        },
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        callback(response);
                       // $ionicLoading.hide();
                        console.log("ajout ");
                    });
                }
            };
        })
```

**here's my code on my controller.js i tried to add a reference recently to my BD so in my controller i set a var ref and i get it the var show's in the console**

```
sendbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            Payement.saveContratEtudant($scope.nb_piece1,$scope.nb_piece2,$scope.shortadresse,$scope.govClt,$scope.villeClt,localiteClt,$scope.voieClt,$scope.cod_logem,$scope.adresse_logem,$scope.govLogem,$scope.gelgLogem,$scope.dateDelivra, $scope.dateEffet, $scope.dateExp, $scope.nomAssure,$scope.prenomAssure,$scope.piece2,$scope.numDocument,$scope.typeContrat,$scope.natureContrat,$scope.piece1, $scope.dateNais,$scope.email,$scope.phone, $scope.IdTrans,$scope.reference, $scope.numDocuemnt, $scope.codePostal, $scope.adresse,$scope.typedocu,$scope.sexeClt,$scope.tarif,$scope.frais,$scope.tva,$scope.tcc ,function (data) {
               console.log("test saveContrat")
                //console.log("date:",date)
                if (data.data.state_code == 200){
                    $scope.local_ = data;
                    console.log($scope.local_.data.data);
                    $state.go('map')
                } else {
                     $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "Alert",
                        template: data.data.message
                    });
                }
            });
```

**this is the exact erro**   TypeError: callback is not a function

```
  at services.js:72
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
    at ionic.bundle.js:29148
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30508)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:24829)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25027)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:24968)
```

Comment: Add more code, because you function `callback()` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: `function callback() {
        if (!hasParams) {
          fn(iteration);
        } else {
          fn.apply(null, args);
        }`

Comment: my problem is that the error only shows when i tried to add a new param ?!

Comment: You should not try to add a param but merged them like this :

    saveContratEtudant: function (allArgsInASignleObject, callback)

Comment: Every time you add a aprameter, you have to change 3 things: the `saveContratEtudant` function, the parameters you use to call `saveContratEtudant` inside the event handler and the data object. If you would create the data object inside the event handler and just pass that, you can add as many parameters you want to the object, without the need to change the function or the function call.

Comment: just to clarify i'm not that good at angularjs , but when i tried to add a new paramter i modify the function saveContratEtudant  at the controller.js and service.js and the one in the php web service.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that in this portion of code :

```
.then(function (response) {
    callback(response);  // <- HERE
    // $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log("ajout ");
});
```

You are calling the function named "callback". But it's not defined. Probably because nothing is passed as param in the last param of this function :

```
saveContratEtudant: function (_nb_piece1,_nb_piece2,_shortadresse,_govClt,_villeClt,_localiteClt,_voieClt,_cod_logem,_adresse_logem,_govLogem,_gelgLogem, _dateDel,_dateEffet,_dateExp,_nomAssure, _prenomAssure ,_piece2,_numDocument,_typeContrat,_natureContrat,_piece1,_dateNais,_email,_phone,_IdTrans,_reference,_numDocuemnt,_codePostal,_adresse,_typedocu,_sexeClt,_tarif,_frais ,_tva, _tcc, callback) {
```

Splitted similar line :

```
saveContratEtudant: function (_nb_piece1,
                              _nb_piece2,
                              _shortadresse,
                              _govClt,
                              _villeClt,
                              _localiteClt,
                              _voieClt,
                              _cod_logem,
                              _adresse_logem,
                              _govLogem,
                              _gelgLogem, _dateDel,
                              _dateEffet,
                              _dateExp,
                              _nomAssure,
                              _prenomAssure ,
                              _piece2,
                              _numDocument,
                              _typeContrat,
                              _natureContrat,
                              _piece1,
                              _dateNais,
                              _email,
                              _phone,
                              _IdTrans,
                              _reference,
                              _numDocuemnt,
                              _codePostal,
                              _adresse,
                              _typedocu,
                              _sexeClt,
                              _tarif,
                              _frais,
                              _tva,
                              _tcc,
                              callback // <- HERE
                              ) {
```

You should check if it's defined before calling it. Or check if your code provided really the function.

Pro tip : you should not have that much arguments in function.

So you should try like this :

```
    .factory('Payement', function ($http, $ionicLoading) {
        return {
            saveContratEtudant: function (params, callback) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url:SAVE_ETUDIANT,
                    timeout: 10000,
                    data: params,
                }).then(function (response) {
                    callback(response);
                   // $ionicLoading.hide();
                    console.log("ajout ");
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

And call it like this :

```
Payement.saveContratEtudant($scope, function (data) {...})
```

Comment: It should still be in scope unless for some reason `saveContratEtudant` doesn't create a closure. It expects 36 parameters, and 36 are passed unless I counted wrong, so the issue is elsewhere. :x I totally agree that once you have to pass more than +- 6 parameters, an object and a callback would be way better. So the data object should be made inside the event listener and  `saveContratEtudant`  should be like function( data, callback ) :)

Comment: the error shows only when i tried to add a new param (_reference) !! do i send them as an object ?

Comment: So you have a problem with numbers of param. Please merge them in one and it will be more easy to maintain. And more compatible with ES 6/7/8 specs. Do you need a sample ?

Comment: Look to my edit. And if it solves your problem, don't forget to mark as "valid" please ;)