# TypeError: callback is not a function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, callback

I am learning node.js and below is my code for the same

**app.js :**

```
const forecastService  = require('./forecast')

forecastService('New York', (error,data) => {

    if(error){
        console.log('Error in getWeatherForecast ')
    }else {
        console.log('data '+data)
    }
})
```

**forecast.js :**

```
const request  = require('request')

const getWeatherForecast = (city,callback) => {

    console.log('printing typeof callback ..'+typeof callback) 
    // prints function 
    console.log('printing callback ..'+callback)
    //prints actual function definition 

    const api = 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=abcdefghijklmn'

    const weather_url = api + '&request='+city
    request({url:weather_url, json:true} , (error,response,callback) => {

        if(error){       
            callback('unable to connect to weather service',undefined)
        }else (response.body.error){
            const errMessage = 'Error in Response :'+response.body.error.info 
            console.log(errMessage)
            callback(errMessage,undefined) // getting error here 
        }
    }) 
}

module.exports = getWeatherForecast
```

**Issue :**

In `forecast.js` , at line `callback(errMessage,undefined)` , I am getting error - `TypeError: callback is not a function`

I have also printed callback in forecast.js as typeof callback = function and callback = actul function definition

But I am still not getting ay clue what is the error .

Can anybody please help ?

I have gone through public posts like [TypeError : callback is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940209/typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function) where all is saying callback is not passed correctly as a parameter which seems NOT the case with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your request-callback definition is wrong. According to the [docs](https://github.com/request/request#convenience-methods)

> The callback argument gets 3 arguments:
>
> - An error when applicable (usually from http.ClientRequest object)
> - An http.IncomingMessage object (Response object)
> - The third is the
>     response body (String or Buffer, or JSON object if the json option is
>     supplied)

So obviously the third paramter is not a function and in fact you're [shadowing](https://medium.com/@mayuminishimoto/understanding-variable-shadowing-with-javascript-58fc108c8f03) the callback from the outer scope. You can fix this problem by simply removing the third paramter:

```
request({url:weather_url, json:true} , (error,response) => {

        if(error){       
            callback('unable to connect to weather service',undefined)
        }else if (response.body.error){
            const errMessage = 'Error in Response :'+response.body.error.info 
            console.log(errMessage)
            callback(errMessage,undefined) // getting error here 
        } else {
           // handle success
           callback(undefined, response.body);
        }
})
```

A word of advice - you should use [Promises and async/await](https://javascript.info/async) instead of callbacks as it greatly increases the readability and the flow of your code.